# How does message-grouping impact distribution of the messages if an existing consumer dies?

Tags: activemq-artemis

The picture below depicts my basic use-case using message groups and Spring-based JMS consumers.

Please note, here the concurrency refers to the config set as shown below:

```
defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("3-10");
```

[image: Msg-Grp with ANYCAST address]

If G1 listener goes down, will the remaining messages of the group be automatically redistributed to another listener?

Comment: @Progman The description is a little similar, but the question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if a consumer receiving grouped messages disconnects (for any reason) then another consumer will be chosen to receive messages from that group. This is detailed in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html):

> Messages in a message group are always consumed by the same consumer, even if there are many consumers on a queue. They pin all messages with the same group id to the same consumer. **If that consumer closes another consumer is chosen and will receive all messages with the same group id.** (emphasis mine)